# Google Places API (Android) Autocomplete just like on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am working on an app in which there is a AutoCompleteTextView that returns suggestions when a user types in. Everything is working fine but I have noted that there is difference in suggestions comparing to maps.google.com. For example when I search "bakery near" in google maps it returns suggestions, but when I search same text on my test app (which uses Google Places API AutoComplete) it returns nothing. Please tell me how can I achieve the suggestions like maps.google.com.

Note: I don't want to show google maps in my app.

Google Maps Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ou3W.jpg , 
Google Places API AutoComplete Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLf7D.png

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the suggestions is a collection that we will set up it's values. Look at this code (the country list will be shown when you type the word): String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_of_countries);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
actv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: bro I am asking about how can I mimic the list of suggestions returned by Google Maps in my app which uses Google Places API AutoComplete.

Answer (score 0):

For a query like, "bakery near ...", I believe you would want to use the [Query Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/query) web service.  Though even with this I do notice some differences between the results on Google Maps and this web service.  I suspect that Google Maps has custom logic that moulds the input/results to be a bit more intuitive.